# Nservicebus ServiceControl SQS support

Tags: amazon-web-services, nservicebus, amazon-sqs

I see that Nservicebus's ServiceControl supports Azure queues, Msmq, Rabbitmq and Sql server. Is there any support for AWS SQS queues? Is there any plugin available?

Cheers,
Marko

Answer (score 2):

NServiceBus supports AWS SQS.
Check out [this example](https://docs.particular.net/samples/sqs/simple/)

Answer (score 0):

No ServiceControl does not currently support the SQS Transport. This ServiceControl proposal would make it easier to support SQS in the future https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/871, if you would like to comment. Or alternatively you could raise a feature request here https://github.com/Particular/ServiceControl/issues/